# I get error when I used UnityAd banner ad in my android app

Tags: android, unityads

I am using below java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String unityGameID = "******";
    private Boolean testMode = false;
    private String placementIdbanner = "baner";
    private View bannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Declare a new banner listener, and set it as the active banner listener:
        final IUnityBannerListener myBannerListener = new UnityBannerListener ();
        UnityBanners.setBannerListener (myBannerListener);
        // Initialize the Ads SDK:
        UnityAds.initialize (this, unityGameID, (IUnityAdsListener) myBannerListener, testMode);

    }

    public void ToggleBannerAd () {
        // If no banner exists, show one; otherwise remove the existing one:
        if (bannerView == null) {
            // Optionally specify the banner’s anchor position:
            UnityBanners.setBannerPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            // Request ad content for your Placement, and load the banner:
            UnityBanners.loadBanner(MainActivity.this, placementIdbanner);
        } else {
            UnityBanners.destroy();
        }
    }

    // Implement the banner listener interface methods:
    private class UnityBannerListener implements IUnityBannerListener {

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerLoaded (String placementId, View view) {
            // When the banner content loads, add it to the view hierarchy:
            bannerView = view;
            //((ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.unityads_example_layout_root)).addView (view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerUnloaded (String placementId) {
            // When the banner’s no longer in use, remove it from the view hierarchy:
            bannerView = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerShow (String placementId) {
            // Called when the banner is first visible to the user.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerClick (String placementId) {
            // Called when the banner is clicked.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerHide (String placementId) {
            // Called when the banner is hidden from the user.
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnityBannerError (String message) {
            // Called when an error occurred, and the banner failed to load or show.
        }
    }

}
```

I get these errors in my logcat as mentioned below :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 9228
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$UnityBannerListener cannot be cast to com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$UnityBannerListener cannot be cast to com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener
        at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Above is my code and logcat output from my android application.

I followed this documentation in my app https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/android/integration-guide-android#banner-ads

Please check this document and guide me how to implement this banner ad from UnityAds.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement IUnityAdsListener at the top :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, IUnityAdsListener
```

Comment: Not work same error. I think not this problem because I already implemet in below class UnityBannerListener.

Comment: But in the tutorial you provided it has implemented it like this where it is initializing the sdk ;
Do this in that class (InitializeAdsScript) :
public class InitializeAdsScript extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, IUnityAdsListener {

Comment: Ok I see that in the documentation also it is not implemented. But it is written. So implement it and then try : IN the documentation it is telling to implement this :IUnityBannerListener

In your game script, import the UnityBanners API, then implement an IUnityBannerListener interface to provide callbacks to the SDK. Use the loadBanner and destroy functions to show or hide the banner. The following script sample is an example implementation for displaying banner ads:

Comment: This line of error :      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$UnityBannerListener cannot be cast to com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener

It means your MainActivity cannot be cast to IUnityAdsListener. Because it is of type Activity. Now if you implement MainActivity implements IUnityAdsListener , then this error will not come. Tell me the error when you do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code(It's 3.3.0 version please check in github link which I given below for new one) :

[Full code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/unity3d/ads/example/ui/main/UnityAdsFragment.java)

```
private BannerView.IListener bannerAdViewListener= createBannerListener();
@Override
public View onCreateView(
    @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unity_banners, container, false);
    this.bannerView= root.findViewById(R.id.top_banner_button);
   int widthInDp = Math.round(ViewUtilities.dpFromPx(self.getContext(), self.topBannerContainer.getWidth()));
                int heightInDp = Math.round(ViewUtilities.dpFromPx(self.getContext(), self.topBannerContainer.getHeight()));
                UnityBannerSize unityBannerSize = new UnityBannerSize(widthInDp, heightInDp);
    bannerView= new BannerView(getActivity(), "bannerads", unityBannerSize);
                bannerView.setListener(bannerAdViewListener);
                bannerView.load();
}

private BannerView.IListener createBannerListener() {
    final UnityBannersFragment self = this;
    return new BannerView.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onBannerFailedToLoad(BannerView bannerAdView, BannerErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            if (self.topBannerView != null && self.topBannerView == bannerAdView) {
                self.topBannerContainer.removeView(self.topBannerView);
                self.topBannerView.destroy();
                self.topBannerView = null;
                self.topBannerButton.setText(R.string.show_top_banner);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBannerLoaded(BannerView bannerAdView) {
            Log.d("UnityAdsExample", "onBannerLoded is called for: " + bannerAdView.getPlacementId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerClick(BannerView bannerAdView) {
            Log.d("UnityAdsExample", "onBannerClick is called for: " + bannerAdView.getPlacementId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerLeftApplication(BannerView bannerAdView) {
            Log.d("UnityAdsExample", "onBannerLeftApplication is called for: " + bannerAdView.getPlacementId());
        }
    };
```

}

> **For more details Use this sample from Unity [github link](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android)**

Comment: Please paste full code here I can't understand first four line . and I can't get this code from your github link.

Comment: It's just sample how to use banner listener . Check in github for full banner demo with other Ads as well

Comment: @Ak23 I will give you full code check it my edited answer.

Comment: I confused because without unityGameId how to show ad?

Comment: this is whole [file](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/unity3d/ads/example/ui/main/UnityAdsFragment.java)

Comment: please refer above link for more details .If possible than clone that repository for better understand

Comment: @b devloper your code and that  file both are different so I cant understand.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: use that file as reference because my code is from version 3.3.0 and that repository is updated before 20 days It's new.